# How to call jQuery on a specific page in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a jQuery function in a file named show.js under /assets/javascript

```
$(function() {
  return $("#accordion").accordion({
  });
});
```

at the moment this function triggering the following error on every page that does not have the id blah

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'accordion'
```

How do I apply this function just to a specific page?

Comment: In jQuery if #blah doesn't exist, the result will an empty object and calling `.blah` or `.accordian` should do nothing. It looks more like you are not including the accordian plugin or jQuery UI at all.

Comment: I am sorry about the mistake in my post it should actually said accordion and not blah (odd). I am trying to use the accordion plugin, but I don't understand how to prevent it from looking for this plugin on every page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to do certain stuff if the accordian plugin is loaded, check in the `jQuery.fn` object which holds all the plugin definitions. If the accordian plugin is loaded, `jQuery.fn.accordian` will be defined.

```
$(function() {
  if ($.fn.accordion) {
    $("#accordion").accordion({});
  }
});
```